# Pyspark load data from Bigquery in local machine

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark, google-bigquery

I am trying to load the data from bigquery table in pyspark but I am facing the below issue

**Code**

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

spark = SparkSession\
        .builder.master('local')\
        .appName("spark-read-from-bq")\
        .getOrCreate()


spark.conf.set("viewsEnabled", "true")
spark.conf.set("materializationExpirationTimeInMinutes", "360")
spark.conf.set("spark.sql.repl.eagerEval.enabled",True)

df = spark.read\
.format("bigquery")\
.option("parentProject", project)\
.option("table",tablename)\
.load()
```

note I created small table and trying to load the whole table in to dataframe

```
**Error**:
Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling o33.load.
: java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: org.apache.spark.sql.sources.DataSourceRegister: Provider com.google.cloud.spark.bigquery.BigQueryRelationProvider could not be instantiated
```

> Pyspark version - 3.3

I have manually downloaded the `spark-3.3-bigquery-pushdown_2.13-0.31.1` jar file from repo and pasted in jars folder.

I have tried manually specifying the path in conf function in spark session

Comment: Have you tried to add to your original spark config ?